# Are == and === the same for objects?

Tags: javascript, equality

I know the difference between `==` and `===` when applied to primitive values.  But for objects, they both seem to be a simple identity comparison.

```
var a = {}
var b = a
var c = {}

a == b // true
a === b // true

a == c // false
a === c // false
```

Is there any situation where comparing two objects will provide different results for each operator, or are they functionally equivalent?

Comment: There's a nice chart here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness the bottom, right corner describes this case.

Comment: Technically all data types are objects because they have properties and methods. What you are describing are object literals.

Comment: @marvin nope, there are primitives in js.

Comment: Here's some good reading @Marvin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types

Comment: @MarkMeyer and Jonas Wilms oh I guess I was mistaken. I was thinking array and strings and thats what came to my head. Thanks Mark for that, now I undestand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, comparing two objects with `==` is the same as comparing them with `===`. Just as comparing two strings with `==` is the same as `===`. If the type of values are the same, both comparing methods will give the same result. [As the specification states](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> ## 7.2.14 Abstract Equality Comparison
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed
>   as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>
>    - Return the result of
>        performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.

Comment: Looking at the specification, I hadn't considered that some objects can be converted to primitives. I think that's what I was missing in my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it

The only way I know to "check for object equality" in javascript is to deep check every possible key (but even then it is just duck type checking)

Answer (score 1):

The extra = in `===` ensures both sides are of the same type. `a` and `c` both are objects, the same type. So `==` or `===` is irrelevant here.

Answer (score -1):

Well... `===` is "compare identity and type".  You've determined that you're comparing two objects (so "type" is the same), that leaves "compare identity", which is the same as `==`.

Likewise, if you compare two `number`s, since you already know they are the same type (`number`), `===` is the same as `==`.  There is nothing special or different about objects vs. primitives here.  It's just that the only type for objects is `object`.